# How to retrieve data from axios promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I use axios to get json object from a file in local dir in Javascript app. The code is as follows:

```js
const getAppSettings = async () : Promise<AppSettings> => {
    return(
    await axios.get(
        CONNECTION.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH
    ).then(response => {
        if(response.status == 200)
        {
            return response.data;
        }
    })
  ); 
}
```

The fields in the source file are:

```json
{
  "TypeA": "Apple",
  "TypeB": "Orange",
  "TypeC": "Pear"
}
```

Then I get the promise response from the axios output.

```js
const appSettings = getAppSettings();
```

I want to get the value TypeB out of appSettings object

```js
const typeValue = appSettings.TypeB
```

It failed because the type AppSettings is not the same as `Promise<AppSettings>`

I don't want to use await modifier in the expression because need to change the tsconfig file from es5 to es2017 / es2022, like below.

```js
const appSettings = await getAppSettings();
const typeValue = appSettings.TypeB;
```

Is there other way to retrieve the TypeB value : Orange from appSettings promise object?

Cannot figure out other way to get the TypeB value from the promise object except using await modifier.

```js
const appSettings = await getAppSettings();
const typeValue = appSettings.TypeB;
```

Comment: FYI there's no reason to check `response.status == 200`. Axios does that for you already

Comment: _TL;DR_ for the duplicate... `getAppSettings().then(({ TypeB: typeValue }) => { /* use typeValue here */ })`

Comment: Can you write down the complete expression before you close my question? What do you mean by "getAppSettings().then(({ TypeB: typeValue }) => { /* use typeValue here */ })"? Thank you.

Comment: That's literally it. Without using `await`, you'd need to use `.then()`. Perhaps this is a little simpler to understand... `getAppSettings().then((appSettings) => { const typeValue = appSettings.TypeB; ...etc })`

Comment: It can be written like that without using await. But looks a bit....

const appSettings = getAppSettings();
const typeAvalue = appSettings.then(res => res.data.typeA);
const typeBvalue = appSettings.then(res => res.data.typeB);
const typeCvalue = appSettings.then(res => res.data.typeC);